# Z-order curve — how to query all nearest neighbors?

Tags: collision-detection, algorithm, curves, search

**TLDR:** How to query all nearest neighbors with the least effort? (Iterating over a bigger neighboring area that's continuous and filtering out elements that are not immediate neighbors?)

---

Suppose the following situation:

- You have a set of 3D points' discrete-grid locations stored in a 1D array (an OpenCL buffer)
- You've assigned each point its Z-index/Morton code
- You sort the array according the Z-indexes
- You generate a lookup-array containing the beginning and end indices of continuous regions of same-Z-index-value particles in the first array

Next suppose that you have an OpenCL kernel which executes for each individual particle. And in that kernel you need to loop over **all nearest neighboring *particles* – not only grid cells –** (including the currently processed particle itself) of the currently processed particle (that could be 9 neighbors for 2D case, or 27 for 3D).

All of the neighboring particles (for a processed particle) are stored in the nearest-neighboring grid cells. Note that the number of particles in one cell can be high (e.g. look at the bottom-right cells of the image below).

**Question:** How can I iterate through all the neighboring particles (ideally in a continuous manner)? If this couldn't be solved via Z-order curve, what other approaches can I use?

*Example pseudocode:*

```
__kernel void process_stuff(...) {
  foreach ( neighboring_particles ) {  // <- how to achieve this efficiently?
    // perform computation
  }
}
```

[image: Neighborhood of the currently processed particle (i.e. processed by OpenCL kernel).\n\nThe red line = Z-order curve.\nThe blue dot = the currently processed particle.\nYellow dots = another particles.\nThe green region = the current particle neighborhood – a set of particles I need to iterate through.]

*Image legend:*

- *Red line* = Z-order curve
- *The blue dot* = the currently processed particle
- *Yellow dots* = another particles
- *Green region* = the current particle neighborhood – a set of particles I need to iterate through

Comment: It sounds like you're looking for space partitioning unless I am misunderstanding your question.

Comment: @NilsOleTimm yes, but to clarify the context: I'm trying to implement [Position Based Fluids](http://mmacklin.com/pbf_sig_preprint.pdf). The authors suggest to use [CUDA Particles](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/samples/5_Simulations/particles/doc/particles.pdf) approach for creating a spatial search structure. I've decided to implement it using the "Building the Grid using Sorting" method. I have all the structures created, but now I need to iterate through all particle's neighbors in one OpenCL kernel, yet I don't know how to do this (efficiently).

Comment: I realize it's a year late, but the [wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Z-order_curve) mentions how to off-set a Z-order index in 2D.